# Check for duplicates in a for of loop

Tags: javascript

I know this can be done using a for loop like so
`for(let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)` but can it also be done in a for of loop?

Here is what I tried:

```
const movies = [{title: 'One'}, {title: 'two'}, {title: '1'}]
console.log('---------------------------')
try{
    for (const movie of movies){
        let i = 0
        console.log('i =', i)
        console.log(movie.title, ' = ',movies[i + 1].title)
        // console.log('movies', movies[i + 1].title)

        if(movie.title === movies[i + 1].title){
            console.log('DUPLICATE')
        }
    i = i + 1
    }
} catch (err){
  console.log(err.message)
}
```

Results:

```
"i =" 0
"One" " = " "two"
"i =" 0
"two" " = " "two"
"DUPLICATE"
"i =" 0
"1" " = " "two"
```

Edit: There should be no duplicates but result says there is.

Comment: so, it works? what's the problem?

Comment: There are no duplicates in movies arr so the if statement should not execute

Comment: your console output suggests otherwise - odd  - oh, wait, you reset i to 0 every loop, put let i = 0 BEFORE the loop - you'll also need to put in a check for the last loop (check if movies[i+1] is undfined) - if you do that then you won't need the try/catch (though, that's perfectly valid to use anyway)

Comment: So how would I do the check? Because if movies does have a duplicate it doesn't console.log "DUPLCATE".

Comment: yes it does, if you fix the code as suggested in the answers below

Comment: I moved the I outside of the for of loop and i also changed movies array to: 
const movies = [{title: 'One'}, {title: 'two'}, {title: 'one'}]
but does it still does not execute
console.log('DUPLICATE') How do I add the check?

Comment: `One` and `one` are clearly different ... perhaps you want to use toUpperCase or toLowerCase to check if you want case insensitive comparison

Comment: I change it to one not One. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare the i outside and make sure `i < movies.length`

```js
const movies = [{title: 'One'}, {title: 'two'}, {title: '1'}, {title: '1'}]
console.log('---------------------------')

// declare i outside the loop
let i = 0
try{
    for (const movie of movies) {
        console.log('i =', i)
        if(i < movie.length) {
            console.log(movie.title, ' = ', movies[i + 1].title)
        }
       
       
        if(i < movies.length && movie.title === movies[i + 1].title){
            console.log('DUPLICATE')
        }
        
         i = i + 1
       
    }
} catch (err){
  console.log(err.message)
}
```

However this is not the best way to do it. Read about `time complexity`

The best way to check for complexity will be to use a `set`. You can read more about `set` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

With set you can do something like this:

```js
  const movies = [{title: 'One'}, {title: 'two'}, {title: '1'}, {title: '1'}, {title: 'two'}]
    console.log('---------------------------')

    // declare i outside the loop
    let i = 0
    let checkForDups = new Set()
    try{
        for (const movie of movies) {
            if(!checkForDups.has(movie.title)) {
                checkForDups.add(movie.title)
            }
            else {
                console.log("DUPLICATE " + movie.title + " FOUND");
            }
            
        }
    } catch (err){
      console.log(err.message)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use a dictionary to remember the titles like this

```
const movies = [{title: 'One'}, {title: 'two'}, {title: '1'}]
const remember = {
}
movies.forEach((movie, i) => {
  if (remember[movie.title]) {
    console.log("i=" + i + ", Duplicate");
  } else {
    remember[movie.title] = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your loop only checks for consecutive duplicates. The only problem I see is that your `i` variable is scoped within the for loop which makes it useless in the algorithm. The problem is easily verifiable in your log where the value of `i` is always 0. What this means is that in your second iteration of the loop, the line: `movie.title === movies[i + 1].title` compares the value in index 1 to itself. What I would do is move the initialization of that variable outside the loop as shown below:

```
const movies = [{title: 'One'}, {title: 'two'}, {title: '1'}]
console.log('---------------------------')
try{
    let i = 0
    for (const movie of movies){
        console.log('i =', i)
        console.log(movie.title, ' = ',movies[i + 1].title)
        // console.log('movies', movies[i + 1].title)

        if(movie.title === movies[i + 1].title){
            console.log('DUPLICATE')
        }
        i = i + 1
    }
} catch (err){
  console.log(err.message)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you want to use a hash.

```
var movieHash = {};

for (const movie of movies){
  if(movieHash[movie.title])
    console.log('duplicate!', movie.title);
  else
    movieHash[movie.title] = true;
}
```